# How to retrieve a cookie in Go?

Tags: cookies, go

I'm getting `undefined: msg` error on the line begining with `tmpl.Execute`. How are you supposed to retrieve cookies in Go?

```
func contact(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method == "POST" {
        r.ParseForm()
        for k, v := range r.Form {
            fmt.Println("k:", k, "v:", v)
        }
        http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{Name: "msg", Value: "Thanks"})
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/contact/", http.StatusFound)
    }
    if msg, err := r.Cookie("msg"); err != nil {
        msg := ""
    }
    tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/contact.tmpl")
    tmpl.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Msg": msg})
}
```

Comment: BTW, you may find gorilla/sessions useful: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/sessions — simple API and you can (very easily) change out the CookieStore for a Redis/DB/other server-side store if you ever need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare `msg` outside the `if`:

```
    func contact(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var msg *http.Cookie

        if r.Method == "POST" {
            r.ParseForm()
            for k, v := range r.Form {
                fmt.Println("k:", k, "v:", v)
            }
            http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{Name: "msg", Value: "Thanks"})
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/contact/", http.StatusFound)
        }

        msg, err := r.Cookie("msg")
        if err != nil {
            // we can't assign string to *http.Cookie
            // msg = ""

            // so you can do
            // msg = &http.Cookie{}
        }

        tmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles("templates/contact.tmpl")
        tmpl.Execute(w, map[string]string{"Msg": msg.String()})
    }
```

Comment: There is no need for the `var msg *http.Cookie` line as it can get defined in `msg, err := r.Cookie("msg")` just as easily.